# Literal operations in vba

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm writing macro code, which read data from .csv file and write that into excel

```
row_number = 5
Range("A5").Activate
Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, linefromfile
LineItems = Split(linefromfile, ",")
If LineItems(0) = "TE-8" Then
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 0).Value = LineItems(1)
row_number = row_number + 1
End If
Loop
```

I'm facing problem with if condition

```
If LineItems(0) = "TE-8" Then
```

This is my if condition, but it never executes because the value from csv is like ""TE-8"" so my if condition fails. I find out this using watch table, if I give string as ""TE-8"" it throws syntax error., is there any solution for this?[image]

Comment: `If LineItems(0) = """TE-8""" Then` (Double `"` escapes a single `"`)

Comment: Or you could check using Instr  Dim IntInstr As Integer
        IntInstr = InStr(str, "TE-8")
        If IntInstr > 0 Then

        End If

Comment: First `Dim  sq as string` and set `sq=vba.chr(34)`. Then using `sq & "TE-8" & sq` should deliver what you need. Cheers.